# echo Yii::app()->getModule() renders array and not the path

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii, module

i am using yii-user which have placed in module folder

```
  <?php echo Yii::app()->getModule('user')->registrationUrl; ?>
```

in an javascript with ajax function which am using in layout

but when i render the path as

**Array**

and not the path which is

```
 /projectname/index.php/user/registration
```

i did checkout in using firebug it displays

```
   xmlhttp.open("GET","Array",true)
```

where as it should be

```
    xmlhttp.open("GET"," /projectname/index.php/user/registration",true)
```

i diid look at most of the posts but did not found how do i achieve it

Please help am stuck please guide.

Comment: var_dump() it to see exactly what you got

Comment: can you show the code for setting url in module?

Comment: @tinybyte thnq am done:)

Comment: @kumar_v thnq am done:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this wrks

```
   <?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/index.php/user/registration
```